# everything moves to right if textview values exceed 2 characters

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have `recyclerview` and for that, I use a specific view. In that view, I have 3 `textviews` and an image button. First `textview` shows me numbers. Others some dummy text. And when my numbers exceed 10(2 characters) everything except numbers moves to the right. How can I handle this?

**Here is my `xml` file:**

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="70dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linlay"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:gravity="center_vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/buses_number"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="1"
                android:textSize="25dp"
                android:textColor="@color/gradStop"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"/>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="300dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/buses_route_name"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingLeft="30dp"
                    android:text="Bus Route"
                    android:textColor="@color/gradStart"
                    android:textSize="20dp"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/buses_cycle_duration"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingLeft="30dp"
                    android:text="Duration"
                    android:textColor="@color/gradStop"
                    android:textSize="20dp"/>

            </LinearLayout>

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/buses_favourites"
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_favorite_border_black_24dp"
                android:background="@color/transparent"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

**Here is the screenshot how it looks like:**

[image]

Comment: I could use "01","02","03" instead of using "1","2","3" but it is not what I want

Comment: You have a LinearLayout in a LinearLayout in a RelativeLayout in a RelativeLayout. Have you considered using 1 LinearLayout? Or perhaps the new ConstraintLayout?

Comment: @White I put my answer please have to look at it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try giving `layout_weight` since you are using linear layout

```
    <RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="70dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linlay"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:gravity="center_vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/buses_number"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="1"
                android:layout_weight = "0.3"
                android:textSize="25dp"
                android:textColor="@color/gradStop"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"/>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight = "0.6"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/buses_route_name"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingLeft="30dp"
                    android:text="Bus Route"
                    android:textColor="@color/gradStart"
                    android:textSize="20dp"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/buses_cycle_duration"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingLeft="30dp"
                    android:text="Duration"
                    android:textColor="@color/gradStop"
                    android:textSize="20dp"/>

            </LinearLayout>

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/buses_favourites"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight = "0.1"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_favorite_border_black_24dp"
                android:background="@color/transparent"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

As you can see  30% space of screen width will be taken by your TextView and 60 % will be taken by Other (LinearLayout) and 10% by your ImageView. I am sure you can change the weight according to your design as you get the gist :)

Comment: it worked but I changed so my textview will take 10% and others 80%

Comment: I am glad I helped you :)

Answer (score 0):

Just set weight 1 to middle Linear layout and set wrap_content for remaining two layout.

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="70dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linlay"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center_vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/buses_number"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="10"

            android:textSize="25dp"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight = "1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/buses_route_name"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingLeft="30dp"
                android:text="Bus Route"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="20dp"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/buses_cycle_duration"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingLeft="30dp"
                android:text="Duration"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="20dp"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/buses_favourites"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"

            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your ImageButton attribute `android:layout_alignParentRight="true"` is not working in linear layout so put outside LinearLayout of ImageButton.

**Like this** and its wo0rking fine for you.

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="70dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linlay"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:gravity="center_vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/buses_number"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="1"
                android:textSize="25dp"
                android:textColor="@color/gradStop"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"/>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="300dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/buses_route_name"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingLeft="30dp"
                    android:text="Bus Route"
                    android:textColor="@color/gradStart"
                    android:textSize="20dp"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/buses_cycle_duration"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingLeft="30dp"
                    android:text="Duration"
                    android:textColor="@color/gradStop"
                    android:textSize="20dp"/>

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/buses_favourites"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_favorite_border_black_24dp"
            android:background="@color/transparent"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>

    </RelativeLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

And whenever you used `wrap_content` it used this property for textView

```
android:ellipsize="end"
```

Comment: my main problem was not moving only button

Comment: main problem was when first textview with numbers have value greater than 2 characters all things move to right

Comment: as you can see in my screenshot 3rd and 4th views's textviews moved to right a little bit

Comment: @Firu 's answer does what I want

Comment: @White yeah actually you are using specific height and width that's why

Comment: yeah, whenever you use Linear layout LayoutWeight property defines the screen alignment according to screen size ratio.